# Use javascript to get total of hours from start to stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been searching this site for weeks trying to find a solution to this and have looked at EVERY question asked about getting the sum of input fields or finding the value of start and stop times but none of them solve my issue.

The included snippet shows a time sheet that I currently am able to input the reg (regular) and ot (overtime) hours and the sum of each row is populated in the total box but at the bottom I have to manually total the column values.

What I would like to do is eliminate the amount of data that has to be input into the form by having javascript calculate the start time and stop time and add the values to the reg, ot and total fields then sum up those columns at the bottom for the grandtotals.

The reason I want to do it like this is that this form is converted into a phone app and the less that is needed to input the fewer mistakes made.

I'm pretty new to this so I'm sure what I have is either incorrect (although it works), or there is a better way to accomplish it with less coding. 
Any direction, input or help is greatly appreciated.

```js
function sum() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('reghours').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('othours').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
         document.getElementById('totalhours').value = result;
      }
}
function sum2() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('reghours2').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('othours2').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
         document.getElementById('totalhours2').value = result;
      }
}
function sum3() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('reghours3').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('othours3').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
         document.getElementById('totalhours3').value = result;
      }
}
function sum4() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('reghours4').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('othours4').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
         document.getElementById('totalhours4').value = result;
      }
}
function sum5() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('reghours5').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('othours5').value;
      var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {
         document.getElementById('totalhours5').value = result;
      }
}

</script>
<script>

                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample').timepicker();

                });
                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample2').timepicker();

                });
                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample3').timepicker();

                });
                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample4').timepicker();

                });

    $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample5').timepicker();

                });
                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample6').timepicker();

                });
                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample7').timepicker();

                });
                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample8').timepicker();

                });
                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample9').timepicker();

                });
                $(function() {

                    $('#BasicExample10').timepicker();

                });
```

```css
.ui-timepicker-wrapper {
 overflow-y: auto;
 height: 150px;
 width: 6.5em;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 outline: none;
 z-index: 10001;
 margin: 0;
}

.ui-timepicker-wrapper.ui-timepicker-with-duration {
 width: 13em;
}

.ui-timepicker-wrapper.ui-timepicker-with-duration.ui-timepicker-step-30,
.ui-timepicker-wrapper.ui-timepicker-with-duration.ui-timepicker-step-60 {
 width: 11em;
}

.ui-timepicker-list {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.ui-timepicker-duration {
 margin-left: 5px; color: #888;
}

.ui-timepicker-list:hover .ui-timepicker-duration {
 color: #888;
}

.ui-timepicker-list li {
 padding: 3px 0 3px 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #000;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
}

.ui-timepicker-list:hover .ui-timepicker-selected {
 background: #fff; color: #000;
}

li.ui-timepicker-selected,
.ui-timepicker-list li:hover,
.ui-timepicker-list .ui-timepicker-selected:hover {
 background: #1980EC; color: #fff;
}

li.ui-timepicker-selected .ui-timepicker-duration,
.ui-timepicker-list li:hover .ui-timepicker-duration {
 color: #ccc;
}

.ui-timepicker-list li.ui-timepicker-disabled,
.ui-timepicker-list li.ui-timepicker-disabled:hover,
.ui-timepicker-list li.ui-timepicker-selected.ui-timepicker-disabled {
 color: #888;
 cursor: default;
}

.ui-timepicker-list li.ui-timepicker-disabled:hover,
.ui-timepicker-list li.ui-timepicker-selected.ui-timepicker-disabled {
 background: #f2f2f2;
}
.auto-style1 {
 text-align: right;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
   }
   #summation {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#174C68;
   }
   .txt {
    background-color: #FEFFB0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
   }   
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jemtech.us/scripts/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jemtech.us/scripts/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

<body>
  <form action="process_form.php" method="post">
    <table align="center" style="width: 498px">
      <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 127px">&nbsp;</td>
    </table>
    <table align="center" class="auto-style6" style="width: 857px">
      <th class="auto-style5" style="width: 47px">Start</th>
      <th class="auto-style5" style="width: 47px">Stop</th>
      <th class="auto-style5" style="width: 43px">Reg</th>
      <th class="auto-style5" style="width: 45px">OT</th>
      <th class="auto-style5" style="width: 51px">Total</th>
      <th class="auto-style5"></th>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample2" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 43px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="RegularHours" id="reghours" onkeyup="sum()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 45px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="OTHours" id="othours" value="0" onkeyup="sum()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 51px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="TotalHours" id="totalhours" style="width: 50px" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample3" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample4" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 43px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="RegularHours2" id="reghours2" onkeyup="sum2()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 45px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="OTTotal2" id="othours2" value="0" onkeyup="sum2()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 51px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="TotalHours2" id="totalhours2" style="width: 50px" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample5" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample6" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>

        <td style="height: 17px; width: 43px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" class="txt" name="RegularHours3" id="reghours3" onkeyup="sum3()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 17px; width: 45px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" class="txt" name="OTHours3" id="othours3" value="0" onkeyup="sum3()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 17px; width: 51px;">
          <input type="text" class="txt" class="txt" name="TotalHours3" id="totalhours3" style="width: 50px" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 17px">
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample7" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>

        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample8" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 43px">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="RegularHours4" id="reghours4" onkeyup="sum4()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 45px">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="OTHours4" id="othours4" value="0" onkeyup="sum4()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 51px">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="TotalHours4" id="totalhours4" style="width: 50px" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td>
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample9" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>

        <td style="height: 26px; width: 47px;">
          <input id="BasicExample10" type="text" class="time" style="width: 85px" />
        </td>

        <td style="width: 43px">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="RegularHours5" id="reghours5" onkeyup="sum5()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 45px">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="OTHours5" id="othours5" value="0" onkeyup="sum5()" style="width: 45px" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 51px">
          <input type="text" class="txt" name="TotalHours5" id="totalhours5" style="width: 50px" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td>
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="auto-style1" style="width: 640px; height: 26px">
      <td><strong>Total Hours</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="txt" name="RegTotal" id="total" style="width: 45px" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="txt" name="OTTotal" id="total" style="width: 45px" readonly/>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 45px">
        <tr id="summation">
          <td style="width: 50px">
            <input type="text" class="txt" name="GrandTotal" id="grandtotal" style="width: 50px" readonly/>
          </td>
          <td style="height: 23px"></td>
        </tr>
      </td>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 35px"></div>
    <hr />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think I follow the question very well. However, if you're trying to make it a phone app, consider using drop-down boxes (Select boxes) instead of input fields. That way, you have absolute control over what can be "chosen" as input (for instance, one won't be able to enter a weird number, say, `37` in the hour field or `74` in the minute field). Let the hour dropdown contain values `00` to `23` and likewise minute as `00` to `59`.

Comment: Like @DhruvSaxena said, these shouldn't be input fields. Too much room for error and people not putting in the time in the proper format. There is a [time input field](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_time), too. But I also don't know how this timesheet works, what formats need to be in each box (12 hour format, 24/military format?), what "reg" and "ot" represent, etc. I'm assuming regular and overtime, but what makes something regular or overtime? You would have better luck on here if you make a super simple example of what you need with clear requirements.

Comment: Ok I've edited the html and added drop down boxes for the times. Reg = Regular time up to 8 hours and OT = Overtime for anything after 8 hours. Standard time as employees will complain if they have to figure out military time.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using a jQuery TimePicker Plugin as mentioned in https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/ together with https://momentjs.com/ for calculations.

Comment: I've added the TimePicker  as you can see in the snippet but I don't understand how the momentsjs will calculate the start time and stop time and how to at that sum to the reg input box or how it will determine if there is overtime or not.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned a date picker will make this easier for both you and your users. Either way, you will need to parse your inputs to get date objects

```
// With date picker
var startDate = new Date(startPicker.value);
```

or

```
// With current select inputs
// Get AM/PM hours - hourSelect should be the select element for hours
var startHrs = periodSelect.value === 'PM'
    ? parseInt(hourSelect.options[hourSelect.selectedIndex].value, 10)
    : parseInt(hourSelect.options[hourSelect.selectedIndex].value, 10) + 12;
// No date provided so use dummy date (1970-1-1)
var startDate = new Date(
    1970,
    1,
    1,
    startHrs,
    minuteSelect.options[minuteSelect.selectedIndex].value; // minuteSelect should be the select element for minutes
);
```

Then calculate the difference between your start and end dates. As mentioned you can use moment.js for this but the regular date object should be sufficient.

```
function getDifference(startDate, endDate) {
    return new Date(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
}
```

Now you can use `difference.getUTCHours()` and `difference.getUTCMinutes` to get the total time worked. It should be trivial to get regular and overtime from the total. Remember to check that the start time is before the end.

Answer (score 0):

> ... or there is a better way to accomplish it with less coding.

The essence of the question seems to be about how to keep the code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), not about whether or not to use a date-picker (though that is also an important decision).

The golden rules in spreadsheet-like apps like this with repeated rows are :

- use classes for elements in the repeated rows
- use ids only for non-repeating element

Here's a general framework :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var overtimeAfter = 8.0; // hours per day

    // *** utility Constructor ***
    function Hours(std, ot) {
        return {'std':std, 'ot':ot};
    }
    Hours.prototype.add = function(otherHours) {
        return new Hours(this.std+otherHours.std, this.ot+otherHours.ot);
    }

    // *** utility functions ***
    function getTime(input) {
        // Here, do whatever is necessary to convert input values to some standard abstraction:
        // for example, 24H string or js Date() object.
        return Number(input.val()); // simplest case
    }
    function timeDiffernce(t1, t2) {
        // Here do whatever is necessary to calculate the time difference
        // between t2 and t1, in whatever abstraction was returned by getTime().
        // For example:
        var t = t2 - t1; // simplest case
        return (t < 0) ? 24 + t : t; // allow for t1...t2 to span midnight
    }

    // *** core functions ***
    function calcDayHours(tr) {
        // here is where you benefit from classes within the table row
        var time1 = getTime($('.time1', tr));
        var time2 = getTime($('.time2', tr));
        var hours = timeDiffernce(time1, time2);
        var std = Math.min(hours, overtimeAfter);
        var ot = Math.max(0, hours - overtimeAfter);
        var total = std + ot;
        $('.reghours', tr).val(std);
        $('.othours', tr).val(ot);
        $(".totalhours", tr).val(total);
        return new Hours(std, ot);
    }
    function calcWeekHours(hours) {
        var weekHours = hours.reduce(function(week, day) {
            return week.add(day);
        }, new Hours(0, 0));
        // these elements are unique, therefore identified by id. 
        $("#regTotal").val(weekHours.std);
        $("#otTotal").val(weekHours.ot);
        $("#grandTotal").val(weekHours.std + weekHours.ot);
        return weekHours;
    }

    // *** master function ***
    function sum() {
        // Assume a table or tbody with id="timesheet"
        var dayHours = $("#timesheet tr").get().map(calcDayHours);
        var weekHours = calcWeekHours(dayHours);

        // if you want wage calculations, then pass `weekHours` to a `calcWages()` function.
        // var wages = calcWages(weekHours);
    }

    // Then attach `sum` as the handler for all kinds of keyup/tap/click/focus/blur events.
});
```

As I say, that's just a framework. There are still decisions to make, eg :

- what you write in `getTime()` will depend on the expected date/time input format (text vs date-picker ...)
- what you write in `timeDiffernce()` will depend on what you decide to return from `getTime()` (Number vs Date ...).
- which ui event(s) should trigger `sum()`.
- how to specify the overtime threshold `overtimeAfter` - hardcoding as above will get you started.
- how to accommodate overtime thresholds on a "per day", "per week" or "per month" basis - wage systems vary.